# Changing the opacity of the background color by converting the color to rgba

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll, background-color

I am using the Jekyll theme [just-the-docs](https://just-the-docs.github.io/just-the-docs/).

I have defined a new custom-callout class and would like to change the opacity of the background color. This is the code I have come up with and it does not work:

`custom-callout.html` file:

```
{% assign callout_type = include.callout %}
{% assign callout_color = site.callouts[callout_type].color %}
{% assign callout_title = site.callouts[callout_type].title %}
{%- assign callout_opacity = 0.2 -%}
{% assign background_color=rgba(${{ callout_color }}, {{ callout_opacity }}); %}

<div class="custom-callout" style="background-color: {{ background_color}}; border-left: 4px solid {{ callout_color }}; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08); padding: 0.8rem; margin-bottom: 1.5rem;">
  <strong class="custom-callout-title" style="color: {{ callout_color }}; display: block; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">{{ callout_title }}</strong>
  {{ include.content | markdownify }}
  {% if include.collapsible_content %}
    <details>
      <summary>{{ include.summary }}</summary>
      {{ include.collapsible_content | markdownify }}
    </details>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

The callout definition in the `_config.yml` file

```
callouts:
  error:
    title: Error
    color: red
```

Note: if I change the line

```
{% assign background_color=rgba(${{ callout_color }}, {{ callout_opacity }}); %}
```

to

```
{% assign background_color=callout_color; %}
```

it all works fine but obvisously there is no opacity applied. It seems clear that the problem is converting the color to rgba in order to apply the opacity parameter. I also tried other functions like `fade` which did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `color-mix()`

You could use [`color-mix()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) like:

```html
{%- assign callout_opacity = '20%' -%}
<div class="custom-callout" style="background-color: color-mix(in srgb, {{ callout_color }}, transparent {{ callout_opacity }});
```

However, please be aware that [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix#browser_compatibility) is spotty, with no support in Firefox.

## Keyword to RGB components map

Define some sort of object map for every HTML color keyword that you may use to convert the keyword into its RGB component equivalent:

```json
{
  "red": "255 0 0",
  "blue": "0 0 255",
  …
}
```

Then use the `callout_color` as the key to this map, whereby it has been injected into the template as the `rgb_map` variable:

```html
{% assign callout_opacity = '0.2' %}
<div class="custom-callout" style="background-color: rgb({{ rgb_map[callout_color] }} / {{ callout_opacity }});
```

If you know there is only a subset of keywords that will be used, you could try  a set of `if` or `case/when` statements instead:

```html
{% case callout_color %}
  {% when 'red' %}
    {% assign rgb_color = '255 0 0' %}
  {% when 'blue' %}
    {% assign rgb_color = '0 0 255' %}
  …
{% endcase %}
{% assign callout_opacity = '0.2' %}

<div class="custom-callout" style="background-color: rgb({{ rgb_color }} / {{ callout_opacity }});
```